# show xml in datagrid with C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, datagridview

```
<customers>
<customer ID="C001">
<name>Acme Inc.</name>
<phone>12345</phone>
<address>value</address>
</customer>
<customer ID="C002">
<name>Star Wars Inc.</name>
<phone>23456</phone>
<address>value</address>
</customer>
</customers>

dataGridView1.DataMember = "customer";
```

when I put datamember as "customer", it shows all the child nodes of the xml in the datagrid. how to show only `ID` & `name` in the grid?

Comment: Can you please provide your code?

Answer (score 2):

To show just Id and Name you could do something like this:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\1.xml");

var customers = document.Descendants("customer")
    .Select(arg =>
        new
        {
            Id = arg.Attribute("Id"),
            Name = arg.Descendants("name").Select(x => x.Value).Single()
        })
    .ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = customers;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can load xml document in grid after that set visibility of required column to true otherwise false.

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();
            data.ReadXml("C:\\xml.xml");
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
            this.dataGridView1.DataMember = "customer";
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in this.dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                if (column.Name == "ID" || column.Name == "name")
                    column.Visible = true;
                else
                   column.Visible = false;

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can switch off unneeded columns like:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["address"].Visible = false; 
//or
dataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
```

It is not the beautiful way for any case. But it is instant.

Comment: thnx..yes it is instant. but is it the right way...if I have so many unneeded columns in the grid?

Comment: It depends on what your goals are. This approach doesn't slow down your application. I've tested this on tables with more than 150 columns. If you'd use a profiler, you could see, that time goes to draw controls. The columns are not visible and the time you spend to draw your one column could be 10 times more than time you spend on process binding and etc. So you CAN use it, move forward and redo it if once you'll se a problem with it. In some cases it is even a good design. I.e. if at some point of your development you decide that users can switch columns on of off by them selfs.

Comment: At least you put simple example in your question and got a simple answer. If the goal you want to achieve is much more different, then put it the question.

Answer (score 0):

Read the xml using the Dataset then set the Data source of Grid to the dataset table.